# Populate Select drop down list with Jquery based on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have 2 buttons and a select dropdown list

```
<button type="button" name="btnmonth" id="btnmonth">Monthly</button>
<button type="button" name="btnyear" id="btnyear" >Yearly</button>

<select id="subscriptions">
    <option value="default">Please Choose a Plan</option>
</select>
```

On the button click of month i need the select drop down list populated with 
4 choices. Or the click of year the list needs to be populated with the 4 year choices. But if you go back and forth between month and year i need the list to not have 1000 of the same choices.

I used jquery .show and .hide on two different selects but the form was submitting both of them even if the year select was hidden so I didnt know which was actually chosen. So it has to be one select drop down

Comment: can you give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can call $("#subscriptions").empty(); before adding options each time

Comment: Try to use two selects and hide it as you told, BUT disable the hidden select using $('select#select-to-disable').prop('disabled', true);

See my answer to more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two selects as you tried, but just .hide() does not remove it from the form.
To remove it from form you can disable it, using `$.prop('disabled', boolean)`

```
<button type="button" name="btnmonth" id="btnmonth">Monthly</button>
<button type="button" name="btnyear" id="btnyear" >Yearly</button>

<select id="subscriptions-monthly" style="display: none" disabled>
    <!-- Monthly select options -->
</select>

<select id="subscriptions-yearly" style="display: none" disabled>
    <!-- Monthly select options -->
</select>
```

In javascript:

```
$('#btnmonth').click(function(event) {
    $("#subscriptions-yearly").hide().prop('disabled', true);
    $("#subscriptions-monthly").show().prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#btnmonth').click(function(event) {
    $("#subscriptions-monthly").hide().prop('disabled', true);
    $("#subscriptions-yearly").show().prop('disabled', false);
});
```

This should work to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `<select>` while it is hidden. In this way the form does not will submit the invisible `<select>`

```
<select disabled id="subscriptions">
    <option value="default">Please Choose a Plan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have working code and just want to not keep on adding values on every button click, just add the "$('#subscriptions').empty()" script in beginning of of your existing buttonclick functions or add the function below at the top of your scripts.

```
$('#btnmonth, #btnyear').click(function() {
    $('#subscriptions').empty()
});
```